# How Can I Connect My Ubuntu 16.04 to Netgear AC1200 Router (model r6220)

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, netgear

How Can I Connect My Ubuntu 16.04 to Netgear AC1200 Router (model r6220)?

Comment: You should write this as an answer to your question.  You can then accept it as the correct answer, and that will help out people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After googling around and trying things for a couple hours, these steps worked for me.  I had to connect to my phone as a hotspot to prove it because it doesn't work when connected to the same wifi hotspot as the router that is running the vpn server.  Hope this helps someone.

```
# install these packages in ubuntu terminal
sudo apt-get install openvpn
sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn
sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn-gnome

# download the client files from the router as 
# a zip file and extract them to my Downloads directory

# open network > edit connections > add > 
# import a saved vpn configuration > select the client.conf file
# that was extracted in the Downloads directory

# edit the vpn connection and set the gateway port to :12973 
# (same as is configured in the router's vpn settings)

# change type to TLS
# select client.crt that was extracted in the Downloads dir
for user certificate
# select ca.crt that was extracted in the Downloads dir for ca certificate
# select client.key that was extracted in the Downloads dir for private key

# click Advanced
# change custom gateway port to 12973
# change virtual device type to TUN
# check the checkbox to accept authenticated packets from any address
```